# Determinging where a "complex" complex function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Say I have the function:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(z-3)^3}$$

I could determine where it is analytic in two ways. Either by computing the limit:

$$\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z}$$

Or by rewriting the function as $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and computing the Cauchy Reimann equations. But in this case both methods will be very long winded.

Is there some other way to determine where the function is analytic that is shorter? What if I am only interested in exploring a well defined domain $D$?

Comment: just in $z=0$ and $z=3$ is neither analytic nor holomorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General case :**

If $g'(w)$ and $h'(w)$ exists and if $g(w) \neq 0$ then
$$ \left(\frac{g}{h}\right)'(w) =  \frac{h(w)g'(w) - g(w)h'(w)}{h(w)^2}.$$
The proof is similar to that of the case of real functions.

**Your problem :**

$g(z) = 1$ for all $z \in D$ and $h(z) = z^2(z-3)^3$. Therefore $f(z) := \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ is holomorphic for all $w \in D$ except $w \in \{0,3\}$ since $h(0) =0 = h(3)$.

Comment: I would say it differently: If $g'(a), h'(a)$ both exist, and $h(a) \ne 0,$ then $(g/h)'(a)$ exists and its value is given by the quotient rule for derivatives.